# Powershell split() function is returning more values than expected

Tags: powershell, split

I have a csv file which conatins line something similar to this

```
"Some KIND of Test","[STATUS]","TESTNAME","VMNAME","TESTTME","SOME PARAMETER"
```

I am trying to parse this. I am using `split` to get `STATUS` and `TESTNAME`

```
$col = $line.split('","') #used .split('`",`"') as well
$col.length #output value is 18
#cl = $line.split(',')
$cl.length #output value is 6
```

Why am I seeing two different values here. In both cases `'` and `","` present same number of times

It seems like I am making some basic mistake. I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [only resolvable overload for `String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) treats the `","` string argument as a character array and splits on each occurrence of *any* of the characters in the array.

Use the [`-split` regex operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-5.1) instead:

```
$col = $line -split '","'
```

---

If you really hate regex, you can force [an overload of `String.Split()` that takes strings as separators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) by explicitly casting the first input argument to a string array:

```
$col = $line.Split([string[]]@('","'),[System.StringSplitOptions]::None)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is pretty straight forward.

Comment: *If you're on version 2.0 where `-split` is not available* Why did you say that?

Comment: @PetSerAl Because my memory is bad, and it's poorly documented

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont use import-csv command like it?

```
import-csv "yourpathtofile"
```

if you want really use get-content you cando it too:

```
$string='"Some KIND of Test","[STATUS]","TESTNAME","VMNAME","TESTTME","SOME PARAMETER"'
$string | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header p1, status, testname, p4, p5 | select status, testname
```